# Pandas division ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, division

I'm having an issue with pandas.div as it throws me an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2490,) (415,)
```

This is the code:

```
 df_daily = df_daily.div(df_daily.nday445, axis=0)
```

it seems like the dimensions of the arrays are different, but everything take place in the same data frame, so I don't know whats happening. Any suggestions?

I tried

`df_daily.iloc[:, 1:3].div(df_daily.nday445, axis = 0)`

and works but I don't understand the logic behind that code, why this works and the other does not work?

Comment: Why not try df_daily = df_daily / df_daily.nday445?

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: @Sagar it says ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (830,) (2,)

Comment: @lanS Is there a way to "convert" a data frame to python code? I did in R but don't know how to do it in python (I'm very new)

Comment: Ok... it seems like the first column which is a text is causing the issue, is there any way python could select only the number columns?

Comment: use `df.select_dtypes([np.number])` to filer out non numeric columns